# What is Premium SSL download service that required to download some ebooks

Tags: amazon

I was asked to get an ebook online from a specific company other than amazon with zero cost  expect you need to make a payment, its a simple payment for something called "Premium SSL download service".

Is this true, is their such paid services provided for some of the ebook or software companies in which the payment will go to secure download service not to the software company itself!.

Comment: Your post makes no sense at all even after multiple readings. "with zero cost expect you need to make a payment": is a word missing some punctuation? "its a simple payment": is the "a" superflous, if so what possesses the simple payment (i.e. what does "its" refer to). Where is the actual question? (Tip: use a question mark on an interrogative question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several such services, where you pay for downloading material over secure connections (that is what SSL indicates), that means your provider cannot listen in on what you do while you visit such a site.

Although there might be exceptions, if you can download books that you have to pay for at Amazon, for a flat rate for the site usage somewhere else, you are paying for illegal distribution of material.

So it is true that there are such sites, but you shouldn't even think about using them. 
Contact the police instead, tell them **who** asked you to investigate this, what ebook you were supposed to get, and that you suspect that you are being set-up to do something that is illegal by the person asking you to get the ebook.